# What does $\mathbb{\bar C}$ denote in complex analysis?

Tags: notation

What does $\bar A$ denote when $ A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$?

I've seen it used in some places as the algebraic closure, other places as $\bar A = A$ \ $ \partial A $ and other places again as $\bar A = A$ \ $\{0\}$.

I should probably add that I don't expect it to be the algebraic closure in my context -- Cauchy's integral type stuff etc. etc.

---

sorry guys, I meant to write $\bar A = A \bigcup \partial A $ rather than $\bar A = A$ \ $ \partial A $. This turns out to be what is meant.

Comment: The symbol $\bar{\mathbb{C}}$ often denotes the Alexandroff compactification of a complex plane, i.e. the set $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$, which extends $\mathbb{C}$ to a compact space. If you meant $\bar A$ for proper subsets $A\subset \mathbb{C}$, please consider editing title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context, but usually it means the [topological closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_closure) of the set $A$.

(it could also mean the conjugate set of $A$, $\{ \bar{z}  | z \in A \}$, so again, it totally depends upon context)

Comment: @user27182: One usually says topological closure to distinguish it from other types of closures, for example from algebraic closures. Just a note: for most nice spaces, the notation $U \cup \partial U$ is the same as the topological closure.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the topological closure, i.e. $\bar A = A \cup \partial A$. In some contexts, it could possibly mean the image of $A$ under the mapping $z \mapsto \bar z$.

By the way, I've never seen $\bar A = A \setminus \partial A$.